# Lenovo graphics issues Windows 10 and BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-10, lenovo-laptop, integrated-graphics

I have the following issue, whenever I hybernate my notebook (in some cases 15-20%) the notebook won't wake up correctly - at least for the graphics part. Any ideas what could cause that?

Once when uninstalling and proceeding with a clean install of Windows10, I saw that effect in the BIOS too, without any OS booted. This would account for a hardware or firmware issue, wouldn't it?I
Thanks for your support! The specs of the notebook are:

Lenovo (15,6 Zoll) Notebook (AMD A4-9125 Dual Core 2x2.6 GHz, 8GB DDR4 RAM, 512GB SSD, Radeon R3, HDMI, Webcam, Bluetooth, USB 3.0, WLAN, Windows 10 Prof. 64 Bit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDOXk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A machine cannot wake up from just BIOS as BIOS doesn't sleep (that I have ever seen).

However, based on a display deficiency in BIOS (which I can understand) does indicate a hardware issue - most likely the GPU chip.

Also 15 to 20 percent of the time is a very high error rate.

Chips on newer Lenovo laptops (say in the last 10 years) are soldered on and not readily replaceable. This is true for most Lenovo laptops.

You may wish to take it to a computer store for additional analysis and see whether they can source a board for you.

Comment: Of cause the BIOS didn't sleep. But switching from boot settings to the actual boot mode provoked the same issue. Sorry for that misunderstanding. Thanks for that advice!